Give even thickness to complex line mesh
I have a simple flat line object of a rose, and I want to give it even thickness and no smoothened intersections. I would also prefer if the solution result is not too high poly.

Solutions I've tried:
Converting to curve, then using Geometry>Extrude and tilting the curve with CTRL+
Problems: It does not have even thickness throughout, and intersections don't properly connect.

Using skin modifier
Problems: Intersections are smoothened. Result is too high poly, however, it can be reduced with a decimate modifier.


Using solidify modifier
Problems: Glitchy intersections. Uneven thickness. "Even Thickness" option does not help.


Import those lines into inkscape, add some line thickness and convert the strokes to lines. There is no way to make good intersections in Blender other than manual work.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah, I was afraid I would have to use a vector program instead. How would I import the lines into inkscape, though? Also, where can I learn more about this workflow? Are you referring to SVG's?

Set the Mean Tilt back to 0° on the complete curve. Then go to the Curve Properties and under Geometry > Bevel choose Object.
Then you need another curve object, just a single straight line in X direction (without any object rotation).
Choose this curve line as Object in the Bevel settings. The length of the line will be the width or thickness of the curve ornament. To make sure the width is evenly spaced on both sides of the base curve, make sure the curve line has its origin in the center.

I would leave it like that because now it is still procedural and you can easily change your mind regarding the thickness etc.
If you want you can afterwards convert it to a mesh, but even with tools like Auto Merge and the Split Edges and Faces option enabled, this might be tedious manual work to get a good mesh from it. For the merging and splitting etc. read more about it in the answers from @Phrogz here: Union/merge overlapping coplanar mesh faces

I tried this, and got basically the same thing as my Geometry > Extrude attempt with the thickness varying across the mesh. I believe the problem may be the base curve itself. I made the base curve by extruding vertices from a circle, with every part connected (using F to connect verts to make an edge) and then converted to curve. How did you make the base curve in your picture? In yours, the thickness is even throughout, whereas on mine, it thins out towards the intersections (see OP) side note: how did you copy mine exactly without the blend file? : )
